# View Spatie Health checks JSON via my own controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in a Laravel 10 project that uses the latest version of the Laravel Spatie Health checks package. I need to be able to view the JSON results of the health checks without re-running the checks and without having to make intermediate API requests from controller to controller.

The package exposes a [controller](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-health/v1/viewing-results/as-json) via a route, but I need to do some processing and so need to use my own controller.

How can I access the JSON results via my controller function below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiSuccessResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiErrorResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiValidationErrorResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;

class HealthCheckStatusController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new HealthCheckStatusController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        try {
            $schema = [
                'label' => 'Progressing',
                'state' => 'progressing',
                'textClass' => 'white',
                'bgClass' => 'info'
            ];

            // TODO: pull spatie health checks JSON here...

            return new ApiSuccessResponse($baseUrl);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'message' => 'Unable to obtain health check status, please try again soon.'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same approach the package does to grab the latest results, as seen in this [controller](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-health/blob/main/src/Http/Controllers/HealthCheckJsonResultsController.php), which is to use the [`ResultStore`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-health/blob/main/src/ResultStores/ResultStore.php) interface as an argument to your controller function and use the resolved object to grab the latest results:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiSuccessResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiErrorResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiValidationErrorResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Spatie\Health\ResultStores\ResultStore;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;

class HealthCheckStatusController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new HealthCheckStatusController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(ResultStore $resultStore)
    {
        try {
            $schema = [
                'label' => 'Progressing',
                'state' => 'progressing',
                'textClass' => 'white',
                'bgClass' => 'info'
            ];

            $latestResults = $resultStore->latestResults()->toJson();

            //do what you need to do with these results...

            return new ApiSuccessResponse($baseUrl);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'message' => 'Unable to obtain health check status, please try again soon.'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't re-run any checks as it simply grabs the latest results from where they are stored, which will be based on how you have the `health.php` configuration file configured.